# CodeIgniter URLs - replacing ( with &#40;

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, imagemagick, special-characters

I'm writing method that creates image file from URI segments. The problem is that when i type http://example.com/class/method/value1/value2/value ( 3 )/value4

And after imagemagick processing, the image is:

```
Value1
Value2
Value &#40; 3 &#41;
Value4
```

I get data in that way: `$this->data = addslashes(urldecode($data));`

Also then I manually change code for generating image to

```
$image->annotateImage($draw, 20, 20, 0, "value ( 3 )");
```

It's fine.

Comment: Are you previously urlencoding the filename in order to use it in the URL?

Comment: Yeah. Manually replacing all special characters using http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: It's same result with ( ) or correspondenting %28 %29 - > &#40; &#41;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html_entity_decode(urldecode($data));
```

that done the dirty work for me. :)